# How can I convert a type to a class in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a class `Client` and I want to create a new class `UpdateClient` but omitting few properties of class `Client`.

```
class Client {
    constructor() {
        this.clients = '';
        this.client_secret = '';
    }
    clients: string;
    client_secret: string;
}
```

I want class `UpdateClient` to be like this

```
class UpdateClient {
    constructor() {
        this.clients = '';
    }
    clients: string;
}
```

Now, I'm sure there will be few approaches in vanilla JS by which I can get the task done, like iterating over all enumerable properties of class `client`, but I don't want to that.

I want a typescript specific solution. I found `Omit` type utility and it's working as expected. However, there's a small issue which I'm unable to fix.

This is the whole code snippet

```
class Client {
    constructor() {
        this.clients = '';
        this.client_secret = '';
    }
    clients: string;
    client_secret: string;
}

type T = Omit<Client, 'client_secret'>
```

I'm getting a type instead of a class. I want to somehow convert this type `T` to the class `UpdateClient` and export it. The exported property needs to be a class because the other module using this one expects a class.

I'm using typescript `v3.7.5`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is for `UpdateClient` to be a class constructor that makes instances of `Omit<Client, 'client_secret'>`, you can write it this way:

```
const UpdateClient: new () => Omit<Client, 'client_secret'> = Client;
```

The declared type `new () => ...` means "a constructor which takes no arguments and produces an instance of ...".  The syntax is either called a constructor signature or ["`new`able"](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/callable#newable) and is part of [the static side of a class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes).

The fact that the above code, assigning `Client` to the variable `UpdateClient`, compiles without error shows that the compiler agrees that `Client` does act like a no-arg constructor of `Omit<Client, 'client_secret'>`.  If, for example, `Client`'s constructor required an argument, or if `Omit<Client, 'client_secret'>` weren't a supertype of `Client`, you'd get an error:

```
class RequiresArg {
  constructor(public clients: string) { }
}
const Oops: new () => Omit<Client, 'client_secret'> = RequiresArg; // error
// Type 'typeof RequiresArg' is not assignable to type 'new () => Pick<Client, "clients">'

class NotCompatible {
  clients?: number;
}
const StillOops: new () => Omit<Client, 'client_secret'> = NotCompatible; // error
// Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

---

Anyway, then this will work:

```
const c = new UpdateClient();
c.clients; // okay
c.client_secret; // error at compile time, although it does exist at runtime
```

Do note that even though `UpdateClient`'s instances are not known by the compiler to have a `client_secret` property, it's still just an instance of `Client` at runtime, so the property will definitely exist at runtime.  If that's a problem you should probably do something completely different.  But since you said `Omit<...>` works for you, I guess that's not an issue.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCIEsCmA7ALtA3gWAFDWmAHsUI0AnAV2DSPIAoBKLPAgtACwQgDpRl0MALzQA5KIDcrNp259EqNAH0ISYOSQYR4qfmgBfaf0UQAXNDLkEKAOa6Cx9CrUa05y9bt5D+PMVIYAKoADgAmYGhI8AJu0ChIAO7QTNBCAHzQAPIAtghoADzRigA0Yo7KquqaohkiRei6fiRkhKlxidAh4ZH1aEy6wPIxEBLQAPRj0EQA1mAAnn5Dis5VaKMT0Ejk5HTQEYRE2cEIIEjQaAjZSKVgIJxElDYc0HnQoURIMEgAHtwY+1R0JckHg-OAoNAAEpIACOlAQGggAEFyDYWHp-JZqLQGMFKAAjRDAQgKQTuCieZiYAzeJoBLJEYJmdpJFLpLK5Aq9UqicorVw1NrQuEIz4ouzjSZbHbkPAbAAqc2CZ1EaCVSCIADMobD4YjxaIXjAUER-lAEDYUGBCWdaOd1WJ4qzmOyAAoIYDTQqktClABE5QgfrSolBuFAkBgADlTbBDsEIggbeiHD6IAB+cwoSjZfFbXQ+TEYADKFxAIEyjOZTuSLoyOTy3piPL5lQFtWgMbQcaOiZt6yl2zocsmiuVjpzefI0AAPtBKChQkhNdYkKFDdw4qa9ubLdbTuciPbx6IPLZRDwgA)